# php print Issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the lines of code below to help me write "`<?php include('like.php'); ?>`" on a page only when the visitor isn't using a a mobile device but it doesn't seem to be working. I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
    if (screen > 699)
        print('like.php');


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CSS and a mediaquery to solve this problem. This goes in a STYLE section, or CSS file.

eg.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) { 
    .selector{display:none;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`screen.width` is a JavaScript construct. PHP isn't JavaScript.

Since PHP runs on the server, and browsers do not provide specifications of the client system with every request, the information is not available to PHP unless you collect it with JavaScript and then send a new request to the server with the data included.

Comment: @Dz.slick: Some things are that much broken that you can not fix it. This is one of these.

Answer (score 1):

See the following link: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/ That will help in finding the device type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native function in PHP that can detect screen resolution. You would need to run a javascript function and pass it on to your php